# Python builtin operator extension

Tags: python, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I create a subclass of float called aF, which contains extra informations and methods. I need to create operations on this class, and in particular I need to be able to compute the product of a normal float with this aF.

How can I extend the `*` operator of the float, so that a float*an augmentedFloat returns an augmentedFloat that fits my needs ?

I know I have to write something like `def float.__mul__()` but I fear that I will delete the standard definition of the operator `*`, for a float.

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Try defining an `__rmul__` method in your `AugmentedFloat` class

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume `f` is a `float` and `af` is an `AugmentedFloat`.  To make both the multiplications `af * f` and `f * af` work, you have to overwrite the [`__mul__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__mul__) and [`__rmul__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmul__) methods.  You don't need to add any methods to the built-in `float` type -- that's not even possible in Python.